# logged user INSERT-ing INTO joined tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

Here is the relational schema of my DB
Where 'articol' is 'paper', 'citare' is 'citation' in English:

[image]

A user is logging in with an ID and a Password and using the interface, he introduced his data in the DB. The code works very well for adding a 'paper' but now I want the user to introduce his 'citations' of the respective 'paper'. The problem is that the code allows introducing the citation in the table 'citation'('citare') but I do not know how to associate this 'citation' to 'paper' ('articol') and to the logged 'user' in the PHP code?

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string(encrypt_decrypt('encrypt',      $_SESSION['password']));

//there is code here...

$AddQuery="INSERT INTO `citare`  (articolCitat, titluCitare, autoriCitare, publicatieCitare, isiCitare, volCitare, noCitare, anCitare, linkCitare) VALUES ('$_POST[narticolcitat]','$_POST[ntitlucitare]','$_POST[nautoricitare]','$_POST[npublicatiecitare]','$_POST[nisicitare]','$_POST[nvolcitare]','$_POST[nnocitare]','$_POST[nancitare]','$_POST[nlinkcitare]' )";
mysql_query($AddQuery, $link);
$last_id_inserted_from_citare = mysql_insert_id($link);
$AddQuery="INSERT INTO artcitare (idArticol, idCitare) VALUES ('{$_POST['hidden_articol']}','".$last_id_inserted_from_citare."')";
mysql_query($AddQuery, $link);
```

Comment: do `mysql_`  functions still work? They are deprecated. You have SQL injection there + the password is not safe without salt and strong hashing. If you want a paper as a requirement for a cite, the paper_id in cite table must not be allowed to be NULL.

Comment: Thank you @DanFromGermay ! I will modify the code. As the site is in construction, now my problem is the INSERT command.

Comment: You should first check weather the paper/book exists (SELECT) and show an error if not, allow the user to insert the paper before you add the cite. I hope I understood your problem and you can solve it :)

Comment: Yes, @DanFromGermay, the paper already exists in the DB! The user has to add his citations. :(

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what you want to know, basically **you cannot** insert into 2 different tables at the same time (hence INNER JOIN does not help in this case). You need to do one first and then the other.
You can wrap those in a transaction, which will make it more robust.

The order is important. You first need to insert you main entities and then fill in the association tables for your many to many. That means that in order to associate "citare", "articol" and "user" they'll need to be inserted first. After that, you'll need to create the appropriate INSERTs in the "artcitare" and "userart" tables to associate them.

Having said that, I think that you might be confusing the process of persisting data into the database from its retrieval process. From your code sample, it seems that the entity "articol" is already persisted in the database, and you're only trying to associate "citares" to it. If the "articol" entity is already persisted, I'd assume that the corresponding "userart" association also exists. Hence, when you're inserting "citares" and associating them to "articols" via the "artcitare" association table you're already linking them to the user.

Comment: you understand well @hasumedic: the associations exist, the INSERT command works very well for all tables, excepting 'citare' ! When I'm inserting "citare" and associating it to "articol" via the "artcitare" association table the linking to the user is not implied!

Comment: If what you're saying is that each "citare" belongs to a "user", you're missing an "idUser" foreign key between "citare" and "user".